# Single user for 2 communities - 1 login or 2 logins?

Tags: community

I have 2 different communities - Partner & Customer. There is this use case of having Partners accessing the Customer community also because of business model client do.

What I was planning to have Permission set for to which Partners will be assigned and use that permission set in Customer community to allow partners login/access.

So the question now is that when Partners are added in Customer community via permission set are they going to get the separate and new login (username+password) for customer community or they can use their existing login credentials (which they use for partner community) to access the customer community?

Comment: Login depends upon the URL, credentials remain the same

Comment: Yes, as you said login credentials remains the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Community in Salesforce, you can choose a unique *domain*.

So lets say you have base URL for community as `https://yourcompany.force.com`, domain for *customers* as `customer` and *partners* as `partner`.

Now if you allow a user with access to both communities, **they can use same login credentials for both communities**:

1. *Customer community* login would be through `https://yourcompany.force.com/customer`
2. *Partner community* login would be through `https://yourcompany.force.com/partner`

Yes, you can use permission sets to [Add Members to Your Community](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_customize_members.htm).

Comment: yeah, I know that single user can have 2 login URL but that was not my question in real. I want to know basically if I assign the partner user to customer community using permission set then does partner user have to use the same login credentials or he will get new login username and password?

Comment: Ah, I had added a comment to question which I didn't add here- `Login to community depends upon the URL, credentials remain the same`. Added in answer as well!